# How to split a long string based on character count

Tags: python, string, list

I am working on creating a list from a long paragraph concatenated based on character count.

As an example: if the character count is set to 100 the string containing a long paragraph should be split in to several lines with a max limit of 100. Lines should not contain incomplete words (if the line contains part of the word it should move to the next line).

I can split the string but I can't think of handling incomplete words (words are set of characters separated from space).

Finally, those lines should be returned as a list.

Comment: Use the tool [`fmt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fmt) or the Python library [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html).

Comment: Please post an example code what you actually want to achieve. .

Comment: If you want to implement this yourself, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, split all text into words:

```
words = [w for w in text.split(' ') if w]
```

Then loop through the words and add them one by one to the new string, until it's length not breaks the limit. In the case add the string to the list of results and start to create the next string.

```
MAX_LENGTH = 100

results = []
r = ''

for w in words:
    if len(r) + len(w) + 1 > MAX_LENGTH:
        results.append(r)
        r = ''
    r += '{}{}'.format(' ' if r else '', w)

print results
```

Comment: Python comes with batteries included. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I don't know, sometimes the goal is just to show raw algorithm implementation. )

Comment: because the chose to break the wheel. Kidding aside we can use textwrap which is included in python library

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example for using the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library:

```py
import textwrap

text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
lines = textwrap.wrap(text, width=100)
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

The method `textwrap` comes with many additional keyword arguments. Have a look into the documentation for more information.